# How to add x&y axes labels for the whole figure not the subfigures?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{1.pdf}\vfill
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.23\textwidth}        
        \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{2.pdf}\vfill
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}        
        \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{3.pdf}\vfill
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.23\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{4.pdf}\vfill
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

I have a figure with 4 subfigures. now I wanna add xlable=Time, ylable=intensity to the whole figure not subfigures.

Comment: It would seem that aligning your (unknown) images to the axes is the real problem.  I would suggest losing all the subfigures and putting each image into a tikz node at specified x,y locations.

Comment: Thx, I try to align the images to a 2*2 shape. Can't the subfigure work it out？Or must I use tikz?

Comment: You don't HAVE to use TikZ, but it will both create the axes and align the images.  Alternatively, you could use a `picture` environment.

Answer (score 2):

Just spelling out John Kormylos comment. Here are a few options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\section*{With subcaption}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}    
 \matrix (fig) [matrix of nodes]{
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-a.pdf}
 \\
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 &
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 \\
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-b.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-c.pdf}
 \\
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 &
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 \\
  };
 \path (fig-3-1.west)  -- (fig-1-1.west) node[midway,above,sloped]{intensity};
 \path (fig-4-1.south)  -- (fig-4-2.south) node[midway,below]{time};
 \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\section*{Without subcaption}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}    
 \matrix (fig) [matrix of nodes]{
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-a.pdf}
 \\
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-b.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-c.pdf}
 \\
  };
 \path (fig-2-1.west)  -- (fig-1-1.west) node[midway,above,sloped]{intensity};
 \path (fig-2-1.south)  -- (fig-2-2.south) node[midway,below]{time};
 \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\section*{Landscape with caption}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}    
 \matrix (fig) [matrix of nodes]{
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-a.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-b.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-c.pdf}
 \\
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 &
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 &
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 &
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 \\
  };
 \path (fig-1-1.south west)  -- (fig-1-1.north west) node[midway,above,sloped]{intensity};
 \path (fig-1-1.north)  -- (fig-1-4.north) node[midway,above]{time};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\section*{Landscape without caption}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}    
 \matrix (fig) [matrix of nodes]{
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-a.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-b.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-c.pdf}
 \\
  };
 \path (fig-1-1.south west)  -- (fig-1-1.north west) node[midway,above,sloped]{intensity};
 \path (fig-1-1.south)  -- (fig-1-4.south) node[midway,below]{time};
 \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

This gives you e.g.

[image]

If you want axes, just replace the `\path` commands in that picture by

```
 \draw[-latex] ([xshift=-2mm]fig-1-1.south west)  -- ([xshift=-2mm]fig-1-1.north west) node[midway,above,sloped]{intensity};
 \draw[-latex] ([yshift=2mm]fig-1-1.north)  -- ([yshift=2mm]fig-1-4.north) node[midway,above]{time};
```

to get

[image]

and similarly for the other options.

**EDIT**: With captions in the figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\section*{With subcaptions in the pics}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}    
 \matrix (fig) [matrix of nodes]{
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-a.pdf}
 \\[-1cm] %<- adjust this to move the height of the subcaptions up or down
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 &
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 \\[0.2cm] %<- adjust this to make the distance to the next row smaller or larger
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-b.pdf}
 &
 \includegraphics[width=1.85in]{example-image-c.pdf}
 \\[-1cm] %<- adjust this to move the height of the subcaptions up or down
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 &
 |[text width=1.85in]| {\subcaption{}}
 \\
  };
 \draw[-latex] ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=2mm]fig-1-1.south west)  -- ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm]fig-1-1.north west) node[midway,above,sloped]{intensity};
 \draw[-latex] ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=2mm]fig-3-1.south west)  -- ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm]fig-3-1.north west) node[midway,above,sloped]{intensity};
 \draw[-latex] ([yshift=-3mm,xshift=2mm]fig-4-1.south west)  -- ([yshift=-3mm,xshift=-2mm]fig-4-1.south east) node[midway,below]{time};
 \draw[-latex] ([yshift=-3mm,xshift=2mm]fig-4-2.south west)  -- ([yshift=-3mm,xshift=-2mm]fig-4-2.south east) node[midway,below]{time};
 \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx, can I still use subfigure? Or must I use tikz?

Comment: I also wanna put the labels (a), (b), (c), (d) inside the graphs. Is that doable?

Comment: @kinderchan It is possible but are you sure you want to do it? (Are the plots 4 in a row or 2 in 2 rows each?)

Comment: Yes, I wanna a 2*2 shape (2 rows and 2 columns), I thought there should be an easy way to just add x&y axes labels based on my code above but I cannot find it out. I also wanna (a), (b), (c), (d) inside the graphs.

Comment: @kinderchan I made an update, please have a look.

Comment: Thx, but I need to use tikzpicture to draw x&y axes, correct? I mean I cannot just add labels directly. Can I also put (a), (b), (c), (d) into any corner of every subfigure.

Comment: @kinderchan I do not understand your question but of course you could move the `(a)` etc. into corners by replacing `|[text width=1.85in]|` e.g. by `|[text width=1.5in,anchor=west]|`. or `east` instead of `west`. Or have the row of subcaptions first.

Comment: Thx, what if I wanna get rid of the subcaption and make the subfigures close to each other? I find `\hspace{-0.25in}` works, but `\vspace` doesn't.

Comment: @kinderchan You can play with the keys `column sep` and `row sep` and of course you could just remove the rows with the `\subcaption`s to get rid of the `\subcaption`s.

Comment: Thx, instead of single x&y lables, can I make two of them? I mean two "Times" in the bottom and two "Intensity" on the left

Comment: @kinderchan Done. Please have a look.

Comment: Thx so much, I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @kinderchan If that worked for you, could you perhaps accept my answer by clicking on the check mark left of it?

Comment: I tried, but I don't have enough reputation.